# GitLab CI : npm command not found in Vue.js project

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, gitlab

I have been playing around with `GitLab CI` and encountered an issue.
**Runner** says:

> npm command not found

**My gitlab-cli.yml**

```
image: node:latest


cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/

before_script:
  - npm install

unit test:
    stage: test
    script:
        - npm run unit
```

The Runner Exceutor was **Shell**. Tried with **docker** executor too. Still the same error.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable your shared executor and enable your registered runner

Answer (score 0):

So what kind of runner you are using ? shared runner ?

here is a sample of my `.gitlab-ci.yml`. hope that will help you!

```
stages:
  - build

variables:
  VERSION: "1.0"

build:
  image: node:12.14.0-alpine3.10
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - npm i
    - npm install -g @angular/cli

  script:
    - ng build 
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist/
```

Comment: Thanks dude!! It's shared runner.  Still the same error :( , Why have you added version variable in it?

Comment: i copied a sample from a repo and i was using that variable to set the artifact version later in the pipline. but this error simply means npm is not on the PATH for some reason. if i were you i would try clearing runner cache.

Comment: ohh okay, i'll try that too